# Not able to pass option parameter in Legacy Flows in Datahub 5.2

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am using Legacy Flows in Datahub 5.2 and passing parameter for harmonization in gradle command.

When I am passing parameter like `-Pdhf.source`, I am getting error like:

> Task '.source=ABC' not found in root project

How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems the issue related to my local and it is working in other environments